# Collision detection is off, Sprite + Tile

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, collision-detection, tile

My game has a player who is constantly moving up. I want it so when he hits the bottom of a block, you lose, and if he hits a block on the side, he just bounces back. There is no physics involved. For whatever reason, the collision detection just isn't working as it as supposed to. For example, in the code below I am resetting the position every time the player hits the bottom. However, it always resets before he even hits the bottom of the tile. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Below is my code for the player (GameIcon),:

```
package com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.sprites;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.GateRunner;
import com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.gameObjects.Block;
import com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.gameObjects.Spike;

import javax.xml.soap.Text;

/**
 * Created by Michael Jan on 8/17/2015.
 */
public class GameIcon extends Sprite {
    private float vX = 3;
    private float vY = 3;
    private float r = 9;

    private Texture texture;

    public GameIcon(int x, int y) {
        super(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("icon_players/icon1.png")));
        setPosition(x, y);
//        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("icon_players/icon1.png"));
//        setTexture(texture);
    }

    public void update() {
            addPosition(vX, vY);
            setRotation( (getRotation() + r) % 360);
            setOriginCenter();
    }

    public void update(TiledMap map) {
        addPosition(vX, vY);
        setRotation((getRotation() + r) % 360);
        setOriginCenter();

        //block
        for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(2).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class))
        {
            Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject)object).getRectangle();
            if(Intersector.overlaps(getBoundingRectangle(), rect))
            {
                setPosition(GateRunner.WIDTH/2 - GateRunner.WIDTH/20, GateRunner.HEIGHT/10);
                if(getY() <= rect.getY() - getHeight() + vX)
                {
                    System.out.println("bottom");
                    setPosition(GateRunner.WIDTH/2 - GateRunner.WIDTH/20, GateRunner.HEIGHT/10);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("side");
                    negateVelocityX();
                    negateRotation();
                }

            }
        }

        //spike
        for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(3).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class))
        {
            Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject)object).getRectangle();
            if(rect.overlaps(getBoundingRectangle()))
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public void addPosition(float x, float y) {
        setPosition(getX() + x, getY() + y);
        setOriginCenter();
    }

    public void negateVelocityX() {
        if(vX < 0)
        {
            addPosition((int)(getWidth()*0.05), 0);
        }
        if(vX > 0)
        {
            addPosition(-(int)(getWidth()*0.05), 0);
        }
        vX = -vX;
    }

    public void negateRotation() {
        r = -r;
    }

    public float getvX() {
        return vX;
    }

    public void setvX(int vX) {
        this.vX = vX;
    }

    public float getvY() {
        return vY;
    }

    public void setvY(int vY) {
        this.vY = vY;
    }

    public float getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(int r) {
        this.r = r;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `getX()`, `getY()`, `getHeight()` do? do `vX` and `vY` are some kind of velocity? Could you include all the other methods that are being called inside the `render()` one?...

Comment: Okay, done. getX() and getY() are part of the sprite class which I am extending BTW.